# No value passed for parameter 'dataSet' error

Tags: android, kotlin

***No value passed for parameter 'dataSet'***
***I'm make the ToDo apps for kotlin in androidstudio,
this error is occured
here is code***

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    data.add(Todo("숙제", false))
    data.add(Todo("과제", false))

    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    ***'''binding.recyclerView.adapter = ToDoAdapter()'''*** }}
data class Todo(val text: String, var isDone: Boolean)
class ToDoAdapter(private val dataSet: List<Todo>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ToDoViewholder>() {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `ToDoAdapter` class have constructor, which needs `List<Todo>` (`class ToDoAdapter(private val dataSet: List<Todo>)`) and you aren't passing any argument to `ToDoAdapter`

inside `()` you should pass `List` of your `Todo`s, so probably it should look like this: `ToDoAdapter(data)`

Comment: aaa is already in the code here '''class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val data = arrayListOf<Todo>()
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)'''

Comment: `ToDoAdapter()` -> `ToDoAdapter(data)`